# SQL Join on user entered Title

Tags: mysql, join

I have a Blog and BlogCategories. A user can enter a category title, which will then pull all Blogs that have the category associated with it.

My set up is:

Blog:

- ID
- BlogCategoryID

BlogCategory:

- ID
- Title

My most recent attempt:

```
$sqlQuery = new SQLQuery();
$sqlQuery->select = array (
 '*',
);
$sqlQuery->from = array (
"BlogEntry",
"LEFT JOIN BlogCategory ON BlogCategory.ID = '$category'"
);
$result = $sqlQuery->execute();
```

How do I achieve this?

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: I updated with my most recent attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` query as follow

```
SELECT * 
FROM Blog a
INNER JOIN BlogCategory b
ON a.BlogCategoryID = b.ID
WHERE b.Title LIKE 'title_here'
```